# Как сделать чтобы job в Jenkins запускался только тогда, когда в git repository появляется новая версия проекта?

Tags: git, github, jenkins

Как настроить конфигурацию job для такой ситуации, нужен ли какой-то plug-in?

Comment: Вроде там сразу есть настройка, чтобы проверять репозиторий (poll vcs).

Comment: Вопрос предельно понятен. Переоткройте, я опубликую ответ.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, может, лучше всё-таки закрыть, например, как «невоспроизводимый или вызванный опечаткой»?